# How to avoid empty grids in seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

I have a dataframe of personal characteristics like school grades, age, weight, and height.
I want to investigate the density distribution of these data within a seaborn `Facetgrid`.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# creation of artifical data
random.seed = 10
high = [random.uniform(3.0,6.0) for i in range(50)]
uni = [random.uniform(1.0, 4.0) for i in range(50)]
math = [random.uniform(1.0, 6.0) for i in range(50)]
bio = [random.uniform(1.0, 6.0) for i in range(50)]
history = [random.uniform(1.0, 6.0) for i in range(50)]
age = [random.randint(15,45) for i in range(50)]
height = [random.randint(150,210) for i in range(50)]
weight = [random.randint(50,100) for i in range(50)]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["value"] = high + uni + math + bio + history + age + height + weight
df["type"] = 100*["final_exam"] + 150*["grade"] + 150*["body"]
df["id"] = 50*["highschool"] + 50*["university"] + 50*["math"] + 50*["bio"]    + 50*["history"] + 50*["age"] + 50*["heigt"] + 50*["weight"]
df["group"] = "A"
df = df[["group", "id", "type", "value"]]
df["para"] =df[["type", "id"]].apply(lambda x: "_".join(x), axis=1)


# Plotting function
def plot_poll(df, **kwargs):

    def plot_densitiy_distribution(data, **kwargs):
        sns.kdeplot(data["value"], shade=True)

    grid_ts = sns.FacetGrid(df, sharey=False, legend_out=True,    hue="group",col="type", row="id")
    grid_ts = grid_ts.map_dataframe(plot_densitiy_distribution)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

# main
plot_poll(df)
```

The dataframe will look like this for a single person but in total 50
persons were interviewed:

```
+=======+============+============+=======+=======================+  
| group |     id     |    type    | value |          para         |
+=======+============+============+=======+=======================+   
|   A   | highschool | final_exam |  2.7  | final_exam_highschool |
+-------+------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+
|   A   | university | final_exam |  2.0  | final_exam_university |
+-------+------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+
|   A   |    math    |    grade   |  3.3  |     grade_math        |
+-------+------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+
   ..............................................................
+-------+------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+
|   A   |    age     |    body    |  27   |        body_age       |
+-------+------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+
   ..............................................................
+=======+============+============+=======+=======================+
```

The figure looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there a lot of empty plots and I would like to rearrange the plot that only grids with data are present. In the columns grids should be shown that have the same `type`. An example (created with Paint) can be seen below.
Furthermore the x-axis is scaled equally for all columns. How can I scale the x-axis individually (even maybe logarithmic).

[rearranged figure (with Paint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSg5r.png)

Thanks in advance for your support,
Christian

Comment: "*As you can see there a lot of emtpy plots which i would like to get rid of*" What does this mean? Should there just be blank sections after the axes are removed? Should the only the axes with data be rearranged into a compact grid? You need to be specific and tell use what *really* want.

Comment: *"How can I scale the x-axis individually (even maybe logarithmic)"* You're already doing this yourself in the y-axis via to the `sharey=False` parameter. Do the same thing with `sharex`.  To set the x-axes as log scale, you can `grid_ts.set(xscale='log'). However, I don't recommend that. If your data are lognormally distributed, you should compute the KDE on the log of the data.

Comment: @PaulH Thanks for your questions.  1)  _"Should the only the axes with data be rearranged into a compact grid?"_ - Yes, that is exactly what i want

Comment: @PaulH _"..., you should compute the KDE on the log of the data_" - Good point! I will consider this idea in my analysis. And also thanks for the hint with `sharex`.

Comment: You're still not being specific. You have 3 variable, 8 plots with data, how should that be arranged? In any case, a seaborn `FacetGrid` isn't going to be able to magically know which axes should be removed and how you want them to be arranged.

Comment: @PaulH I extended my question with an additional figure how it should look like in the end. (considering only the empty facet grids and not the x-axis topic)

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to hide plots for presentation purpose (but keep the overall grid structure):

```
    for (i,j,k), data in fg.facet_data():
        if data.empty:
            ax = fg.facet_axis(i, j)
            ax.set_axis_off()
```

Comment: This is perfect.